# How to hide fractional part if it is zero?

Tags: c#, math

How to hide fractional part of a double or float number if it is all zero. I am converting a floating point number to string and its display Mantissa part even if it is zero. For example:

```
double number = 123.00;
string strNumber = number.ToString(); // it shows "123.0", what I need is only "123"

double secondNumber = 123.2234;
string strSecondNumber = secondNumber.ToString(); // it shows "123.2234" as needed.
```

Is there any built-in solution in .NET to get it done?
Thanks

Comment: Can you try something like `number.ToString("#.#")` but guess might round off

Comment: I tried to find same question but could not in first find it. However,  here now we have another good solution to the problem!

Comment: The correct term is fractional part, not mantissa.

Comment: Um, good question - but you meant "fractional" or "decimal", not "mantissa" (try googling each of those words for further explanation)

Comment: editted the post: "Mantissa" to "Fractional"

Comment: are you sure strNumber is "123.0"? for me it is "123"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the overload of `double.ToString()` that takes in a format string, and pass it `"R"`:

```
double number = 123.00;
string strNumber = number.ToString("R"); 

double secondNumber = 123.2234;
string strSecondNumber = secondNumber.ToString("R");
```

Comment: yes that was the magic little thing i was looking for, thank you :-)